# Pattern search naive method

Tags: c, algorithm, pattern-matching

Write a program to implement brute-force string matching.Analyze its time efficiency.
Following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int opcount=0;
int searchpattern(char *ms,char *ss,int m,int n)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<=n-m;i++)
  {
    j=0;
    opcount++;
    while(j<m&&(ms[i+j]==ss[j]))
    {
      j++;

    }
    if(j==m){
      //printf("Pattern found in main string");
      return i;
    }
  }
  //printf("Pattern not found");
  return -1;
}
int main()
{
  int i,j,p,n,m;
  char *text;
  char *subtext;
  printf("Enter text below :\n");
  fgets(text,256,stdin);
  printf("Enter subtext below:\n");
  fgets(subtext,256,stdin);
  n=strlen(text);
  m=strlen(subtext);
  p=searchpattern(text,subtext,m,n);
  if(p==-1){
    printf("Pattern not found\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("Pattern found at index %d",p);
  }
  printf("No. of operations is %d",opcount);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get segmentation fault.If anyone can point out my error I will be grateful.

Comment: So is this a question about time efficiency like before the code or about segfault like after the code?

Comment: You should try playing with `gdb`

Comment: What is it about the algorithm tag that attracts so many "fix my homework" questions?

Comment: Well gotta start somewhere.Algorithm being one of the important areas we want to ensure that we understand all topics thoroughly.Stackoverflow provides a great platform for learning.

Comment: There is one more error which I realized.By using fgets it stops reading when newline character is read.So in my actual parameters it should be m-1,n-1.

Answer (score 0):

Already the first `fgets` accesses an uninitialized pointer and reads into memory that has not been allocated. 
Replace the raw pointers by an array sized accordingly:

```
char text[256];
char subtext[256];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pointers to read input into memory, this would be a good time to learn about memory allocation and de-allocation.

The    `text, subtext` pointers should be allocated memory, the size of which should be equal to the size of what you want to read.

```
char* text = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
char subtext = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
```

And don't forget to free the memory you have allocated at the end of your program using `free`.

```
free(text);
free(subtext);
```

The `malloc` and `free` functions are library functions found in `stdlib.h` and so you have to add this header to the beginning of the file.